# .change() vs .on( "change", handler ) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an issue when I use jQuery to handle the trigger of change on my drop-down.

I use 2 pieces of code:

```
//---------- Case 1
$(document).on("change", "#drop-down-id", function () {
    alert(this.value);
});
//----------Case 2
$("#drop-down-id").change(function () {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

The first one running smoothly, but the second one is not triggered when I start the browser, but after I refresh my site, it works.

Do you have any idea?

My jQuery version: 1.11.1, and I've tested on Chrome 38, Firefox 32 and IE 11.

-- Edit:
@JanR & Cheery: It seems like this:

```
<select id="drop-down-id">
    <% arr.each do |option| %>
        <option value="<%= option %>"><%= option %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

I've used Rails 4.1 and *arr* is an array contains numbers.

-- Edit:
I found out that the issue came from the Asset Pipeline of Rails, not the jQuery.

I put the JS code inside a script tag and it works in both case, but when I put it in the assets folder, the issue happens.

Thank you for your quick replies!

Comment: Can you reconstruct the problem at, let say, jsfiddle.net? Does this select created dynamically or not?

Comment: case 1 can be used to elements even if your element still not exists in the html.  case 2 should be used inside the dom ready function to work, so that all elements in the html are loaded.

Comment: @Cheery, yes the select created dynamically. I haven't use jsfiddle.net yet, :), so let me try it!

Comment: @roullie, you mean that in case 2, the dom hasn't loaded yet?

Comment: @haitran `yes the select created dynamically.` it means, probably, that at the moment of the listener assignment it does not exists. With refresh browser reads from cache and select on its place almost instantly. You should call `.change(` when element already exists.

Comment: @haitran yes that is possible.  use case 2 like JanR showed below and it would work.

Comment: @Cheery I've used _$(document).ready_, but it still not work, any idea?

Comment: @haitran can not tell without seeing the whole code, not just a portion of it.

Comment: your case 1 is working because it is pointing on your whole document and your control maybe loaded dynamically.

Comment: In the future, for a question related to HTML/JavaScript, your server-side language is of no consequence. You want to show people the same code that the browser sees, i.e. the HTML produced by the server. However, a tiny snipped of just a `<select>` isn't going to help solve complex interaction problems. You usually need to create a pared-down test case using the minimal amount of code (HTML, JavaScript, and CSS) to reproduce your problem. Spending time creating this test case will teach you something, usually show you the problem, and if not, it provides helpers with a solid foundation.

Comment: P.S. In HTML, if you want the value of an option to be the same as what it displays, you do not need a `value="…"` attribute.

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks, in my real project, I've used other value for the option! I will try the pared-down as you said!

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using case 1, since it is composed document to load change event, if you choose the elements are **dynamically** generated, use case 1 will be effective.

Also jquery doc said, .change () is a shortcut for .on ("change", handler), so I think eventually will use .on callback.

Comment: Yes, I've used Case 1 in my project, but as you said (and also in the jQuery document), _.change () is a shortcut for .on ("change", handler)_, so what is the different?

Comment: As the final callback .on, so I think there will be performance advantages; the other maybe removed, like .live

Answer (score 3):

When using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), keep in mind that:

- **Case 2, is an alias: `.change(...) === .on("change", handler)`** - If the `selector` is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to
  as direct or directly-bound (The handler is called every time an event occurs on the selected elements). In this case, if you want to bind something successfully to an element, you need to ensure it is already loaded.
- **Case 1: `.on("change", selector, handler)`** - If the `selector` is provided, the event handler is referred to as
  delegated (The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants that match the selector). In this case, you don't need the element to be loaded or not at the time of your binding.

The benefits of doing it one way instead of the other are well explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878976/908879) from [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click).

Answer (score 1):

In case one you are binding the change event on the document level to an element that's part of the document. At this stage it doesn't matter whether it exists or not yet (say it's created later or loaded later).

In the second case you are binding the event to an element that has to exist in the DOM already or the binding will fail. What can be happening is that your javascript is firing before the element has been loaded on the page.

Try wrapping case 2 in a $(document).ready() function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//----------Case 2
        $("#drop-down-id").change(function () {
              alert(this.value);
        });
});
```

This will ensure your javascript won't fire until the DOM is ready.

Comment: Can you post your html etc? It's really hard to troubleshoot otherwise as it depends on how you are generating the page. If you are dynamically adding the object I would recommend you use case 1.

Comment: As pointed out the in the comments we would neeed to see more than that, is there any other javascript running on the page? What does the DOM structure look like etc.

Comment: no, thats .on("change", callback) and .on("change","parent", callback)
the second one deals with event delegation.

Comment: This is a REALLY useful answer and will ensure you consider how the on change event is applied within the DOM or document, thanks JanR